# how to get CSP version of vue2.x

Tags: vue.js

from vuejs.org installation, runtime-only build is fully CSP-compliant. 
after git clone , npm run build i got the vue.runtime.js version.

but it doesn't work in chrome extenstion enviroment.

so, could you just give me a csp version of vue2.x(vue.csp.js), like vue1.x ?